# Требования Play маркет к целевому API на 09/2020г

Tags: android, google-play

Всем привет, готовлю к публикации в маркете приложение на 28 api, возник вопрос примет ли маркет приложение или придётся мигрировать на 29 api?

Comment: Добавьте к себе в закладки: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk Если приложение новое - придётся, если обновляете уже опубликованное - то до ноября ещё можно

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку